# Dynamically generate / omit HTML attribute in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig, escaping, quotes, conditional-operator

I want to generate a div with a specific HTML attribute present or absent in it, in function of if a variable `my_var` has been defined or not. If it has been defined, its value should be used as the according attribute.

`my_var` is either not defined or equal to a value consisting of several words separated by a space (software needs these, I know it's not usual...).

I've tried the following:

```
<div class="container" {{ my_var ? "data-my-var='" ~ {{ my_var }} ~ "'" : ""}}>
</div>
```

But this escapes the quotes I use and yields sth like this in my output, with `my_var = hello there how are you`:

```
<div class="container" data-my-var=&quot;hello there how are you&quot;>
</div>
```

This does not change when I escape the quotes using

```
"data-my-var=\"" ~ {{ my_var }} ~ "\""
```

instead of what's written above.

I've also tried to simply omit the quotes, so do sth like:

```
"data-my-var=" ~ {{ my_var }}
```

which resulted in the attribute `data-my-var` being output with no quotes whatsoever; hence only recognizing the first word of the value of `my_var`.

So how can I reach what I want?

Comment: What about `{% if my_var %}data-my-var="{{ my_var }}"{% endif %}`? Not sure if I understand your question..

Comment: True, would have been a way too, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables and concatenations with variables are not marked as safe by default. You will need to apply the filter `raw` to mark the output as safe. Also you can omit the second part if you just return an empty string

```
<div class="container"{{ my_var ? (' data-my-var="' ~my_var ~ '"')|raw }}>
</div>
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/5aa88q)

---

Another method, as commented by @Bossman is to use an `{% if ... %}{% endif %}`

Comment: Splendid, worked like a charm. I've accepted your proposition as an answer as it's closer to my syntax, hope that's okay for @Bossman!

Comment: @DevelJoe totally fine, as long as you get what you need. I always think of "Occam's razor" and readability to anyone else but myself :)

Comment: And just FYI, my syntax parser actually reports that you're not allowed to write twig tags within tags, only twig expressions (although the parsing works perfectly with the twig tag solution employing `{% if ... %}{% endif %}`). But well syntax parsers and twig is another book chapter..